# Javascript - Replace entire DOM + script files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an ajax request that returns an entire HTML page with references to js and css files.
Now, I do succeed replacing the entire html and everything works fine, But, I can't call js functions right after the replace is made. They are undefined. Is there a way to know that the browser finished replacing the DOM and to evaluate the JS code that is referenced by the new HTML?

The only way it worked for me is to use setTimeout of 2 seconds and than call the functions from the JS files referenced by the new HTML. But, this solution is not good for me. I'd rather use something like document ready event of jQuery but it doesn't work for that scenario, it doesn't wait for the browser to evaluate the new js code.

This is the code that works for me, but needs to be changed for something else than setTimeout

```
objXHR.done(function (msg) {
    document.write(msg);
    window.setTimeout(function () { Initialize(window); }, 2000);
});
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Maybe you first need to call `document.open`, then write with `document.write` and then `document.close` to tell browser you are finished and trigger javascript evaluation. I haven't tried this, I'm just guessing.

Comment: If you replace the entire DOM, then aren't you replacing the context of your own objXHR?

Comment: What you are trying to do is extremely difficult to pull off right.  IF you can return a *partial* HTML -- just what would go inside the `body` element - then it becomes much easier.  Just set up a something like `<div id='inner_body'></div>` and replace the contents of that div, leaving the rest of the document intact.

Comment: I need to replace also the "Head" tag and all the JS and CSS references